# How display the number of decimal places is uncertain float NSNumber to UILabel as in json?

Tags: objective-c, json, type-conversion, nsstring, nsnumber

I have an `NSNumber` object from `json`.
I want to convert to `NSString` for display, but the result is weird.

```
    NSNumber *num = @(98.9);
    NSString *numString = [num stringValue];// output 98.90000000000001
```

The `JSON` I got from the server is

```
{"Price": 98.9}
```

I need to show it to the UILabel `98.9`, But the result is `98.90000000000001`
The `number` of `decimal` places is uncertain
Maybe

```
{"Price": 98.91}
```

or

```
{"Price": 98.901}
```

I need to display the same as in `json`

Comment: You might want a `NSNumberFormatter` or use `stringWithFormat:` depending if it's for the UX or not.

Comment: Result is not weird. It is how floating value works. 98.9 may be 98.89999 or 98.90001. Such floating behaviour is what named such value as "float".

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `stringWithFormat`:

```
NSNumber *num = @(98.9);
NSString * numStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.4lf",[num floatValue]];
```

Comment: The number of decimal places is uncertain